# Как сократить до одной строчки

Tags: python, python-2.7

Мне известно, что эту часть кода можно сохранить до одной, строчки, но я не знаю, как, помогите нубу)

```
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

Comment: Засунуть все аргументы в один через +.

Comment: target.write("\n".join([line1,line2,line3]) + "\n")

Comment: Спасибо, оба варианта рабочие.